# How can I change my application's language from Fragment using akexorcist/Android-Localization library version 1.0.8

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm using a library called akexorcist/Android-Localization version 1.0.8 (I'm using this version 1.0.8 b/c of backward compatibility) to change my application's language in realtime (without restarting the Activity) I was able to change the app language from the activity. But, I can't figure out how I can change the language from a fragment.

Here is some code to further explain my **problem**.

### **Activity Login Code:** This changes the app's language from the login page (This works fine).

```
package com.example.eee.ui.login;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.akexorcist.localizationactivity.LocalizationActivity;
import com.example.eee.R;

public class Login extends LocalizationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setLanguage("am"); // This is the library's method and it works fine.
    }
}
```

### **Setting Fragment Code:** I want to change the app's language from here using  the mentioned library

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MaterialSpinner languagePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.language_picker);
        languagePicker.setItems("English", "አማርኛ", "Oromifa", "ትግርኛ", "Somali", "Afar"); // Languages
        languagePicker.setOnItemSelectedListener((MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>) (view1, position, id, item) -> {
            if (item.equals("English")) {
                changeAppLanguage("en");
            } else if (item.equals("አማርኛ")) {
                changeAppLanguage("am");
            }
        });
    }

    // Change Language
    private void changeAppLanguage(String locale) {
        // I want to change my language here (using the mentioned library)
    }
}
```